# Does the following convergence in Banach spaces hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $X$ Banach and $B \colon X \to X$ be linear, bounded operator, injective so that it is invertible on its range $R(B)$.

Take $y_n,y \in R(B)$ such that $|y_n-y| \to 0$ and consider $x_n,x \in X$ such that $y_n=B x_n, y=B x$ which exist by injectivity.

Now as $$0 \leftarrow y_n-y=B(x_n-x)$$ due to the injectivity of $B$ I can conclude that $x_n \to x$, right?

Comment: If $R(B)$ is closed then $B^{-1}$ is continuous and so $x_n \to x$. Otherwise $x_n$ nees not converge to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not without further assumptions on $R(B)$. If $R(B)$ is closed (and hence Banach in its own right), this follows from the open map theorem (note that you want $B^{-1}$ to be continuous.

As a counterexample consider the inclusion $\ell^1 \to c_0$. Let $y_n = (\frac 1n, \ldots, \frac 1n, 0, \ldots)$ ($n$ times $\frac 1n$), $y = 0$. Then $y_n \to y$ in $c_0$ (hence in the image), but $\|{y_n}\|_1 = 1$, and $\|y\|_1 = 0$, therefore $x_n = y_n \not\to y = x$ in $\ell_1$.

---

As requested by OPs comment, let's elaborate on the counterexample. We consider
$$ c_0 = \{ (x_n) \in \mathbf C^{\mathbf N} : \lim x_n = 0\} $$
the vector space of sequences with limit zero. It can by shown, that $c_0$ is Banach with the norm
$$ \|x\|_\infty := \sup_{n \in \def\N{\mathbf N}\N} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{x_n}. $$
On the other hand, let's look at the space of absolutely summable sequences
$$ \ell^1 = \left\{ (x_n) \in \mathbf C^{\mathbf N} : \sum_{n \in \N} \abs{x_n} < \infty  \right\} $$
which is Banach with the norm
$$ \|x\|_1 := \sum_{n \in \def\N{\mathbf N}\N} \abs{x_n}. $$
As summable sequences must have limit zero, $\ell^1 \subseteq c_0$. As $\abs{x_n} \le \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{x}_1$ for each $n$, $\norm x_\infty \le \norm x_1$ for $x\in \ell^1$. That means that the map $B\colon \ell^1 \to c_0$, $x \mapsto x$ (the inclusion) is continuous.
The argument above shows, that the inverse (restricted to $\ell^1$) is not, as the sequence $y_n := (\frac 1n, \ldots, \frac 1n, 0, \ldots)$ tends to zero in $\norm{\cdot}_\infty$, as $\norm{y_n}_\infty = \frac 1n \to 0$, but not in $\norm{\cdot}_1$, as $\norm{y_n}_1 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the ansswer. I don't understand your notation for the counter example: what is $c_0$?

Comment: @carlos85 I wrote something additional about it.

Comment: Thanks, it is now clear to me now